# What can cause one program to make another unresponsive?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two C# Winforms applications, which both work fine when run separately. The problem is that when I run program A, program B seems to fail to react to button presses.

*What are the candidates for causing this?*

Details:

- Program B's buttons still (sorta) look like they're being pressed: they briefly enter their "depressed" state, but don't stay there when I keep the mouse button down (as they usually would)
- Program B remains unresponsive for only as long as program A remains open. I can close program A to restore functionality to B and then start A again, which stops B.
- Although unresponsive to button presses, Program B's UI is still updated with streaming information when Program A is running.
- Both applications interface with unusual peripherals:

  - Program A connects to a USB webcam and an Android tablet (via USB and ADB port forwarding)
  - Program B connects to two USB devices that act like serial ports. One is a relay and the other sends a continuous stream of data.
- Program A is unaffected by whether or not program B is running,

I need both programs to run at the same time and on the same PC. *What should I be looking for when trying to fix this mess?*

---

**Update:** After some extending fiddling, I found that occasionally the buttons will respond. In practice this means hammering the mouse until one of the clicks registers. Whilst this is not ideal, it works. Unfortunately, this has exposed the presence of a new problem: keyboard presses act like long presses.

I.e. pressing <kbd>A</kbd> once causes Program B to act like it has been held down.

*Does this give any clues about the cause and/or how to fix it?*

Comment: It seems like they are competing for a common resource.  Do your libraries have any kind of "singleton" pattern implemented?...or a mutex?  I doubt we'll be able to narrow this down without more details...  =\

Comment: What is this "streaming information"?  Bogging down a UI thread with an onslaught of 'streaming information' is pretty easy.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Pretty sure that's not what's happening here. No shared libraries or other resources.

Comment: @HansPassant I considered that, but A) the UI updates to show the information being streamed and B) the problem seems linked to the other program.